# Dynamically creating objects in LINQ expression that inherit from abstract base class

Tags: c#, linq, generics, abstract-class

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T : Tweet
    {
        protected string _name;
        public abstract string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract List<Tweet> tweets { get; set; }
    }
```

Which is sub-classed by several different classes (their names are `Person`, `Place` and `Organisation`). I store lots of instances of the `Entity` class in a `List<T>` instance.

I have a separate method that is used to combine different `List<Entity<Tweet>>` instances into one another, joining them on `Entity.Name` and merging their containing `List<Tweet>`:

```
private static List<Entity<Tweet>> joinLists(List<Entity<Tweet>> list1, List<Entity<Tweet>> list2)
{
    List<Entity<Tweet>> joined;

    joined = list1.Union(list2)
                  .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                  .Select(o => new Entity<Tweet> // this is wrong as class is abstract but at this point I don't know what concrete class o is?
                  {
                      Name = o.Key,
                      tweets =
                          o.SelectMany(x => x.tweets).ToList()
                  }).ToList();

    return joined;
}
```

Unfortunately as Entity is an abstract class, I cannot create an instance of it, so how can I dynamically determine the actual concrete class of the `o` instance in the LINQ expression. I have a separate method that does this based on a string representation of an object's class name, but I would like to know how this would be achieved with LINQ (method below is my implementation for use elsewhere in my application):

```
private static Entity<Tweet> createEntity(string className, Tweet tweet, string value)
{
    Entity<Tweet> entity = null;
    Type t = Type.GetType("FinalUniProject.NERModels." + className);
    entity = (Entity<Tweet>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    entity.Name = value;
    // Allow for inverted index by adding tweet to NamedEntist List<TweetModel>
    if (entity.tweets == null) entity.tweets = new List<Tweet>();
    entity.tweets.Add(tweet);
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem in inserting the complete implementation of your `createEntity` function inside the `select` statement of your linq and return the Entity object

Comment: @Jayant How will that allow me to still do the `.SelectMany` on `o` as shown inside of the object initializer?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType())`, but you're better off with an abstract `Clone` method...

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of a class: JoinedTweetList or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line of code below do not give any compile error for sure. Haven't checked all aspects. U sure this wont work ?

```
joined = list1.Union(list2)
                      .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                      .Select(o =>
                      {
                          Entity<Tweet> entity = null;
                          string className = o.First().GetType().Name;
                          Type t = Type.GetType("FinalUniProject.NERModels." + className);
                          entity = (Entity<Tweet>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                          entity.Name = o.Key;
                          // Allow for inverted index by adding tweet to NamedEntist List<TweetModel>
                          entity.tweets = o.ToList().SelectMany(x => x.tweets).ToList();
                          return entity;
                      }).ToList();
```